# Is An Input A Variable?

Tags: python, variables, input

probably an extremely obvious question but I'm fairly new to python and was wondering if an input is considered a variable? Just something like:

```
name=input("What Is Your Name?")
```

Comment: `name` is a variable in that statement, and can be referred to later on to get the value stored in it, `input()` is a function, that you are calling to display the string

Comment: `name` is a variable; the input is its value.

Comment: To understand what it does, try `print (name)` on the line immediately after.

Comment: @SimonFraser `name` is a [`NAME`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming) for an object. There is no value stored in `name`. If `name` is deleted the value isn't necessarily deleted.

Comment: Well in python everything is a variable ... or to put it another way everything is variable. You can assign ``input = 'blub'`` and then it's a string. But if you don't do it then ``input`` is a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: @PeterWood and is there no value in explaining to the OP in the terms they're familiar with?

Comment: @SimonFraser I don't know what OP is familiar with.